# Spotify Android Intent Play on Launch

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify

I'm trying to get Spotify to resume playback when launched from an intent but not having much luck.  I think I'm close I can get Spotify to launch, and if I specify a search for an artist it will auto play but really I just want it to resume what I was last playing which I have not gotten to work yet.  This site made it seem possible but with what I have so far Spotify just launches and goes to the search screen.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#PlaySearch

Here is my code so far:

```
        final Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
        intent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.MainActivity"));
        intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS, "vnd.android.cursor.item/*");
        intent1.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "");
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (intent1.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
```

Comment: You said you could get this to auto play if you specify an artist. I can't get this to work.  The search results come up but no auto play. Any ideas?  If I use your solution below after performing search for artist, it just plays what was playing before instead.

Comment: can you post what you have in code so far?

Comment: added another answer for showing how to play by artist below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out so I thought I would post the solution I used.  I looped through all the packages that subscribe to Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON and that is when I found the component name I needed to get this to work:

```
private void playPlayMusic() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.internal.receiver.MediaButtonReceiver"));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.internal.receiver.MediaButtonReceiver"));
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY));
    sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
}
```

Comment: Great, I used it for play music, but it does not play music when Spotify is not running in background. Can you suggest what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a routine for searching by Artist and playing in Spotify:

```
public void playSearchArtist(String artist) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.music", "com.spotify.music.MainActivity"));
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS, MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ENTRY_CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST, artist);
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, artist);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Just opened the search for the artist, but then didn't play. Then I upgraded to Spotify Premium to see if that makes a difference - and now it works!!  Stupid. Oh well. Now I'm struggling to make playing a playlist work...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059466/how-to-automatically-play-playlist-in-spotify-android-app

Comment: That makes sense they do lock down a lot of features when you're not on premium.  Glad you got it working.  This is the site where I got most of my information.  Should help you tweak it for playlist playback.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#PlaySearch