# How to get packages that subscribe to a certain intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I came across this SO question here: [Spotify Android Intent Play on Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524063/spotify-android-intent-play-on-launch)

and was very impressed that he managed to manually find out what packages were explicitly subscribed to a certain `KeyEvent`. He mentioned, and I quote,

> looped through all the packages that subscribe to
>   Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON

How did he do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
List list= context.getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers(intent , 0);
```

Comment: Actually, [that is a broadcast action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON), so you would need to [use `queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).